# Why do I have ReferenceError: person is not defined?

Tags: node.js

Simple code

```
var person = {
  name: 'Andrew'
};

person.age = 25;

debugger;

person.name = 'Mike';

console.log(person);
```

I am running it in debug mode

```
debug> n
break in playground/debugging.js:1
> 1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var person = {
  2   name: 'Andrew'
  3 };
debug> n
break in playground/debugging.js:5
  3 };
  4 
> 5 person.age = 25;
  6 
  7 debugger;
```

Anyway I can not manipulate person object

```
debug> person
repl:1
person
^

ReferenceError: person is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:59:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:120:6)
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`person` is not a valid command when in debug mode. See the [list of commands](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) available when in debug mode.

If you want to watch the person object as you step through, then use `watch`

```
debug> watch('person')
```

This will keep printing out the value of person as your step through.